# Display power bi report on my desktop application

Tags: asp.net, powerbi

I'm a beginner in Power BI and I need to know if it's possible to integrate Power BI reports into a desktop application or web site.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to use our javascript API to embed the report in your application. https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-integrate-a-power-bi-tile-or-report/

Answer (score 0):

Power BI has a new feature called [Publish to Web](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/de-de/publishtoweb/). This will create a link you can embed in an IFRAME on your website. If your desktop app has a Web control, then I assume you could use the link there as well.

Comment: Publish to web is only appropriate if you intend your data to be public.  Seem like the wrong solution to this question.